# Inferring return type of generated async functions

Tags: typescript

I expect to be able to infer the return type of async functions when they are yielded as values from a generator.

In the example below, inference of the type of the yielded async functions seems to work, (they are detected as `() => Promise<string>` ). However, `T` is not able to be inferred as `string` and ends up `unknown`.

I have reduced a more complex problem to the example below (see [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpKa6N)). It retains all the essential features I think I need for the real case.

The commented code indicates a bit more about the reason for needing to infer *both* `J` and `T`. Crucially, extensions to `Job<T>` can carry job-specific metadata.

Can anyone work out how to compose type definitions that can infer both `J` and `T` in the below case, so that the settlement type is `JobSettlement<string, () => Promise<string>>` instead of `JobSettlement<unknown, () => Promise<string>>`

[image: JobSettlement has T of unknown]

I speculate this is one of the unhandled cases of [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) but I am unsure how to put it into a shape where TypeScript *can* handle the inference.

```
type Job<T> = () => Promise<T>

export interface JobFulfilment<T, J extends Job<T>> {
  job: J;
  status: "fulfilled";
  value: T;
}

export interface JobRejection<T, J extends Job<T>> {
  job: J;
  status: "rejected";
  reason: unknown;
}

export type JobSettlement<T, J extends Job<T>> =
  | JobFulfilment<T, J>
  | JobRejection<T, J>;

export async function* createSettlementSequence<T, J extends Job<T>>(
  createJobSequence: () => AsyncGenerator<J>
): AsyncIterable<JobSettlement<T, J>> {
    for await (const job of createJobSequence()){
        try{
            const value = await job();
            yield {
                job,
                value,
                status:"fulfilled",
            }
        }
        catch(reason){
            yield {
                job,
                reason,
                status:"rejected"
            }
        }
    }
}

const settlementSequence = createSettlementSequence(async function* () {
    yield async () => "foo"
    yield async () => "bar"
    yield async () => "baz"
})


// const settlementSequenceWithMetadata = createSettlementSequence(async function* () {
//     yield Object.assign(async () => "foo", { task: 0})
//     yield Object.assign(async () => "bar", { task: 1})
//     yield Object.assign(async () => "baz", { task: 2})
// })
```

Comment: For those curious about the full-blown case, the untested code is sketched at https://github.com/cefn/watchable/blob/810677713473072c28ed68c536448954bc0c2f40/packages/nevermore/src/nevermore.ts

Comment: Wouldn't this all be simpler (and give you `T` -> `string`) if you only had _one_ generic parameter? https://tsplay.dev/m3oRAm

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. It would simplify, but as commented in the post, inferring `J` is core. "The commented code indicates a bit more about the reason for choosing this implementation approach - that you can infer Job structure, which can carry metadata". The full-blown example is in the linked github repo. See https://github.com/cefn/watchable/blob/810677713473072c28ed68c536448954bc0c2f40/packages/nevermore/DESCRIPTION.md#job-annotation-for-control-and-reporting Once I've an answer for inference I aim to add more tests and worked examples where per-job metadata is a core feature.

Answer (score 0):

A naive attempt to simplify this to have just one generic binding (J extends Job) and to infer `T` via a `Fulfilment<J extends Job<unknown>>` fails as per [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLrk4w)

[image]

However, this can be addressed by explicitly asserting the type via...

`(await job()) as Awaited<ReturnType<typeof job>>`

It seems surprising that Typescript needs to be told this, but hey.

```
type Job<T> = () => Promise<T>;

export interface JobFulfilment<J extends Job<unknown>> {
  job: J;
  status: "fulfilled";
  value: Awaited<ReturnType<J>>;
}

export interface JobRejection<J extends Job<unknown>> {
  job: J;
  status: "rejected";
  reason: any;
}

export type JobSettlement<J extends Job<unknown>> =
  | JobFulfilment<J>
  | JobRejection<J>;

export async function* createSettlementSequence<J extends Job<unknown>>(
  createJobSequence: () => AsyncGenerator<J>,
): AsyncIterable<JobSettlement<J>> {
  for await (const job of createJobSequence()) {
    try {
      const value = (await job()) as Awaited<ReturnType<typeof job>>;
      yield {
        job,
        value,
        status: "fulfilled",
      };
    } catch (reason) {
      yield {
        job,
        reason,
        status: "rejected",
      };
    }
  }
}

const settlementSequence = createSettlementSequence(async function* () {
  yield Object.assign(async () => "foo", { task: 0 });
  yield Object.assign(async () => "bar", { task: 1 });
  yield Object.assign(async () => "baz", { task: 2 });
});

for await (const settlement of settlementSequence) {
  if (settlement.status === "fulfilled") {
    const { value, job } = settlement;
    console.log(`Task ${job.task} successfully returned ${value}`);
  }
}
```